# Cannot connect to vSphere Webclient

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I have a problem connecting to the vCenter Web Client. I can connect and do some administration from the VLAN that the vCenter Server is on and this is working fine.

But if I connect from our client computers VLAN I can connect to the vCenter Server and see the welcome page but as soon as I click on the "Log in" on the right (Redirect to :9443/vsphere-client/ ) this just times out. It’s not a VLAN routing issue as first thought as I can connect to the vCenter Server from this VLAN via the vSphere Vlient.

I have looked in the security profile of the hosts and the vCenter IP isn’t restricted to any particular subnets.  Any ideas?

This is on hosts running ESXi 5.1 and the vCenter Appliance 5.1

**EDIT:** I have removed and re-configured the defualt gateway on the vCenter appliance, this made no difference. I can SSH to the vCenter from this VLAN fine and I can also use the "Browse Datastore Web Client"